# Restoring Entire Project from .git folder

Tags: git, backup, restore

I have a web project which I have been working on for some time. I use GIT with SourceTree to keep track of changes but foolishly had no proper backups in place.

I had about 50 commits and wanted to wipe the slate clean and start with a new initial state so I deleted the .git folder, however I messed things up in SourceTree which ended up deleting all the project files (although the folders remain for some reason).

I still have the .git folder which I deleted. My question is, can I recover the last known project state from this folder, and how would I go about doing this?

Comment: Let's just make thing more clear. First you write "I deleted the .git folder". And then you write "I still have the .git folder which I deleted". Could you please explain what really happened? Could you please fix your question? Right now it has to many contradictions. And it is impossible to understand current state.

Comment: FYI, the ".git" dir actually is a git repo. Not the files you were tracking using it.

Answer (score 19):

Say you have a folder like this (assuming windows here, but makes no difference):

```
c:\myrepo\.git
```

with "myrepo" being empty otherwise, just having .git folder which has its full contents, you can just do

```
cd c:\myrepo
git reset --hard HEAD
```

Which should recover all your files.

Note: Advise to do "CD into the .git folder and type git status" is wrong, that is expected to reply with "Fatal - this operation must be run in a work tree".

Comment: This worked for me after using "git init" first. Otherwise I got the "fatal..." error you mention above.

Answer (score 0):

If you really have the folder containing `.git`, then as far as I know all you have to do is restore this folder and Git should recognize it as a repository.  If you also messed things up in SourceTree, then you delete the affected branches, or even create a new repo, and use your `.git` as the source for information.

Comment: I have the .git folder itself. I deleted the entire repository from SourceTree (after deleting the .git folder), so I have the isolated .git folder but no other information.

Comment: I have the .git folder itself. I deleted the entire repository from SourceTree (after deleting the .git folder), so I have the isolated .git folder but no other information.

I have tried adding the .git folder into the original project folder (now empty) and creating a new project from working copy from within SourceTree, however I get an error "git status failed with code 128: fatal: bad object HEAD"

Comment: CD into the `.git` folder and type `git status`.  What do you see?  Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17291995/push-existing-project-into-github) to see how to push out to a new repo.

Comment: I'm within the .git folder and git status returns "Fatal - this operation must be run in a work tree"

Comment: Is your `.git` folder inside another repo folder?

Comment: No, it is in the the project folder which is within the standard wamp root on C:/. The only repository root I had was the project folder itself.

Comment: I'm out of ideas...then maybe you have another problem that the Git folder has a problem.

Comment: Fix the worktree error, then push out to a new clean repo.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Maybe I don't understand GIT in as much depth as I should, in fact I know I don't. But If I have the .git folder that was initially inside the project, am I not able to "re-build" the entire project in its original location or another location?

Comment: Yes, you're right...the `.git` file should be all that you need.  But your Git file has _another_ problem, which you need to fix first before you worry about creating a new repo.

Comment: I also encountered the "Fatal - this operation must be run in a work tree" when restoring old repos from .git directories. It turned out I just needed to `git init` before doing any `reset`s or `log`s.