# Is there any way to recovery gitlab repositories from data directory like below?

Tags: git, gitlab, recovery

[image: data directory]

There are repository directories like project.a.git in git-data. I tried to name one to .git, and enter "git status" in shell, but got "this operation must be run in a work tree".
I don't have a backup tar file, is there any way to recover gitlab repositories from data directory ?

Answer (score 4):

1. Copy/Move the Repositories
   We want to make a copy of the GitLab data to restore from by copying the .git folders.
   Since your GitLab server is likely positioned on a remote sever, you can copy using `scp` to copy over SSH.

   - **Remote GitLab**

     ```
     src=~/gitlab
     server=server.local

     mkdir -p "$src"
     scp -r "$server:/var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories/@hashed" "$src"
     ```
   - **Local GitLab**

     ```
     src=~/gitlab
     server=

     mkdir -p "$src"
     cp -r /var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories/@hashed "$src"
     ```

   Please make sure to change;

   - `server.local` to your server's domain name or IP address, and
   - `/var/opt/gitlab` to the path to your GitLab data.
     If you're using Docker, you will need to [recall your location from the installation instructions](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/install/docker.html#set-up-the-volumes-location). You may need to login as root, or make the folders accessible to your non-root user.

   **Note**: Make sure you have read access to the directories.
2. (Optional) Reinstall GitLab
   Since the GitLab installation is, likely, corrupt now. You'll need to [perform a fresh install](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/install/).

   **Note**: You will need to recreate any groups you want to import. You can find all the groups you'll need to make with the following script.

   ```
   #!/bin/bash

   src=~/gitlab

   repos() {
       for repo in $(printf "%s\n" "$src/@hashed"/*/*/* | grep -Pv '\.wiki\.git$'); do
           readarray -d "/" -t segments <<< $(git config --file "$repo/config" --get gitlab.fullpath)
           echo ${segments[0]}
       done
   }

   repos | sort | uniq
   ```
3. We can get all the repositories using the glob:

   ```
   "$src/@hashed"/*/*/*
   ```
4. This includes `.wiki.git` directories which seem to hold the project's wiki.
   We don't want these so we can use grep to filter out any which don't (`-v`) end with `.wiki.git`

   ```
   printf "%s\n" "$src/@hashed"/*/*/* | grep -Pv '\.wiki\.git$'
   ```
5. Now we will interact with each repository individually.

   ```
   for repo in $(printf "%s\n" "$src/@hashed"/*/*/* | grep -Pv '\.wiki\.git$'); do
       # interact with each repo
   done
   ```
6. Get the GitLab path from the repository's `config`.

   ```
   path=$(git config --file "$repo/config" --get gitlab.fullpath)
   echo $path
   # peilonrayz/repository
   ```
7. Copy the `.git` folder to your local repository directory.

   ```
   dest=/data/repositories
   mkdir -p $dest/$path/.git
   cd $dest/$path
   cp -r $repo/* .git
   ```
8. [restore the files in the project's directory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41312852).

   ```
   git --work-tree . reset --hard HEAD
   ```
9. Push everything to the new GitLab server.

   ```
   origin=ssh://$server/$path.git
   git remote add origin "$origin"
   git push -u origin --all
   git push -u origin --tags
   ```

### TL;DR

**Note**: If you're on Windows; you will need to [run Bash on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6413377).

```
#!/bin/bash

# Change to your values
data=/var/opt/gitlab
src=~/gitlab
dest=/data/repositories
server=server.local

mkdir -p "$src"
scp -r "$server:$data/git-data/repositories/@hashed" "$src"
ssh "$server"  # reinstall GitLab

for repo in $(printf "%s\n" "$src/@hashed"/*/*/* | grep -Pv '\.wiki\.git$'); do
    path=$(git config --file "$repo/config" --get gitlab.fullpath)
    origin=ssh://$server/$path.git

    mkdir -p $dest/$path/.git
    cd $dest/$path
    cp -r $repo/* .git
    git --work-tree . reset --hard HEAD
    if [ "$server" != "" ]; then
        git remote add origin "$origin"
        git push -u origin --all
        git push -u origin --tags
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

The actual repositories reside in the `git-data/repositories`.

Ideally you would [restore](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/raketasks/backup_restore.html#restore) the whole GitLab installation by importing a backup from the `backups` directory though.

Comment: I had not create any backup before the server crashed. So there's not any backup.tar in "backups" directory.

Answer (score 0):

Answer comes from @Peilonrayz but still I had to do some try and error to get my repos locally so here it goes in short format how to get the repos from the GitLab data folders to your local machine:

```
#!/bin/bash

src=./data/git-data/repositories
dst=./gitlab-repos_bk

for repo in $(printf "%s\n" "$src/@hashed"/*/*/* | grep -Pv '\.wiki\.git$'); do
    # interact with each repo
    path=$(git config --file "$repo/config" --get gitlab.fullpath)
    echo path: $path
    echo repo: $repo
    mkdir -p $dst/$path/.git
    cp -r $repo/* $dst/$path/.git
    git -C $dst/$path --work-tree . reset --hard HEAD
done
```