# How to unpack GitHub backups to get the real source code?

Tags: github, backup

The GitHub backup zip has following structure:

[image]

[image]

But I don't know how to extract it to get the real source code.

When I do a normal extraction, all I get is the second screenshot, which is not the real souce code.

I did a search on Google, but could not find a solution.

It seems like GitHub also does not have docs about this question.

Does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: What do you mean "extract"?

Comment: To get the source code.

Comment: You have the repo directory, so see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/41312852/3001761

Comment: @jonrsharpe I did a check, and found it is not the answer. I think you might want to do a backup from your github settings, account, to know what I was saying.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I have solved this problem.

#### In general

```bash
mkdir pure_source_code
cd pure_source_code
git clone ../repositories/<your_account_name>/*
```

#### For bash script

```bash
#uncompress_it.sh

directories=$(ls -d ../1772b8d2-550f-11ee-803e-4a843c258251/repositories/<your_account_name>/*)

for directory in $directories; do
  git clone $directory
done
```

```
bash uncompress.sh
```