# How to place an existing directory on github?

Tags: github

I have a folder with files and I want to place this folder on github.

What i am doing:

1. I create a new repository on github, with a name identical to my
   directory (**myfolder**).
2. console: git init
3. Through the console I find my folder: cd **myfolder**
4. console: git remote add origin
   https://github.com/acount/**myfolder**.git
   After that i take next error: fata:remote origin already exists.

What is wrong?

Comment: Based on the error you're receiving, it looks like you're already in a repository.  Did you create this directory within a directory that has already been initialized?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is in this post:
[Push existing project into Github](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17291995/push-existing-project-into-github)
thanks Rann Lifshitz.

I maked this and it's working:

> Follow below gitbash commands to push the folder files on github repository :-
>
> 1. $ git init
> 2. $ git cd D:\FileFolderName
> 3. $ git status
> 4. If needed to switch the git branch, use this command :
>          $ git checkout -b DesiredBranch
> 5. $ git add .
> 6. $ git commit -m "added a new folder"
> 7. $ git push -f https://github.com/username/MyTestApp.git TestBranch
>          (i.e git push origin branch)

⸺ copied from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41437583