# Upload local repository to github.com

Tags: git, github

I have a git repository which exists fully locally inside my PC. I want to create remote clone of it onto the github.com. How can it be done?

Comment: So you have a local repo which has never been pushed to GitHub?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yes, that's it.

Comment: Please read the documentation: https://gist.github.com/mindplace/b4b094157d7a3be6afd2c96370d39fad

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Push existing project into Github](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17291995/push-existing-project-into-github)

Comment: He say he has a repo, but all answers have git init or worse git clone  in them. Correct answer here https://gist.github.com/mindplace/b4b094157d7a3be6afd2c96370d39fad

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**It looks like a very basic question, still follow the below steps**

Step 1: You need to create a github repository first

Step 2: Then copy the URL of the github repo

Step 4: Then add remote for the github repo (`git remote add origin "copied repo URL"`)

Step 3: Then clone the repo (Readme files will cloned) (`git clone "copied repo URL"`)

Step 5: Then add file (`git add * or git add . or git add file name`)

Step 6: `git commit -m "your message"`

Step 7: Then push it (`git push origin "branch name"`)

> Login to github and check your Repository

Comment: This answer is not for uploading a local repository but rather for uploading a local codebase. The right answer for the question is in the docs linked by @TimBiegeleisen above (https://gist.github.com/mindplace/b4b094157d7a3be6afd2c96370d39fad)

Comment: If you already initialized the repo with `git init`, you can still do this without cloning the git here. So if you already have data which can't be moved (for example because of a project directory), you to `git init`, follow these steps and leave out step 3. Git bash will then tell you to use '--set-upstream-branch` the to branch, but that's easy as it's just following the steps given by the terminal.

Comment: This answer is nonsense. Is a sequence of totally unrelated git commands.

Answer (score 11):

Add a [new repository in GitHub](https://github.com/new) and then in the folder on your computer that you want to upload to GitHub run the following commands (changing `my_username` and `my_project` to your situation):

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m "initial commit"
git remote add origin https://github.com/my_username/my_project.git
git push --set-upstream origin master
```

#### Notes

If this is your very first time setting up git on your local machine, then you need to add your username and email:

```
git config --global user.name "Bob"
git config --global user.email bob@example.com
```

In the future when you make changes you can simply do the following:

```
git add .
git commit -m "description of what I changed"
git push
```

I also use `git status` a lot to see what has changed or is ready to commit.

Answer (score 4):

my way to upload existing local repository

1. Make new repo(give a name but don't click any combo box to initialize).
2. Open git bash in the local repo.
3. add :
   `

- git remote add origin https://github.com/..../(reponame).git
- git branch -M main
- git push -u origin main

name "origin" and "main" up to you.
make sure you are logged in on local git bash

Answer (score 4):

1. You first need to create a GitHub repo "**without a README.md**" file.
2. On the next page,GitHub itself displays you the commands you need to run to push/upload your local repo.
3. Go to your local repo through the terminal, paste those commands and you'll be good to go.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way in my opinion is to simply download the GitHub desktop client, there is an option to add a repository by dragging and dropping files or just navigating to the folder and then uploading it to GitHub account.

Answer (score 1):

**1.** If you have Github CLI then you just have to run the command- **`gh repo create`** after initialising your local repo with git.

**2.** If you don't have the Github CLI installed you can get it
[from here](https://cli.github.com/manual/installation) .