# How do I migrate a local git repository to github?

Tags: git, github, version-control

I have a git repository (with a github remote).

Then, I deleted the repository in github.

I want to recreate the git repository in github with full history (i.e. branching, commit and merging history).

How do I achieve it?

I had tried creating a new repository via web UI, cloning it, copying files one by one but it is too timeconsuming.

Comment: You should use  git remote add origin once you created a repo on GitHub. Then you can push it to GitHub.

Comment: just publish local to github

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Push existing project into Github](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17291995/push-existing-project-into-github)

Answer (score 16):

(i'm going to use `git.example.com` here instead of GitLab, as there is nothing specific to GitLab, except probably the possibility to create a a git repository via the webinterface; but these days, there are plenty of different providers with the same functionality)

1. create a new git repository via the webinterface, e.g. `https://git.example.com/bfg/frobnozzel.git`
2. create a local bare clone of your (local) repository (in this example closing into `/tmp/new-frobnozzel.git`:

   ```
    git clone --bare /path/to/local/repository /tmp/new-frobnozzel.git
   ```
3. in the newly created bare-clone, change the `remote` to the new github repository:

   ```
    cd /tmp/new-frobnozzel.git
    git remote set-url origin git@git.example.com:bfg/frobnozzel.git
   ```
4. push your entire repository to the new remote:

   ```
    cd /tmp/new-frobnozzel.git
    git push --mirror origin
   ```
5. (optionally) switch your working repository to use the newly created remote repository as the main upstream, use:

   ```
    cd /path/to/local/repository
    git remote set-url origin git@git.example.com:bfg/frobnozzel.git
   ```

   you might want to do an initial synch just to be sure that everything is working (`git pull`)

Btw, there's also some [Github documentation that covers this](https://help.github.com/en/articles/duplicating-a-repository).

Comment: I guess this doesn't leave the newly created bare local repository actually usable, and the understanding is that the user is supposed to clone it from github to resume local development?  It might be good to be explicit if that's the case, and also to state why the bare clone is required in the first place (which the github docs you mention also doesn't explain).

Comment: I think "bare-close" in step 3 above should be "bare clone"

Comment: i've added the information you requested; but actually i think it is unrelated to the question, where the local repository would still have github as a remote; the question (and answer) is really about restoring all the branches and tags

Answer (score 3):

The answer is simple: create a new repository on github (with the same name) and push the local repo to the remote(which should be correct)

Make sure that you push everything.

Comment: not so simple anymore: github's default branch has been renamed to 'main', whereas many old repos still have the 'master' default branch.

Comment: What us the problem? Just create a repository without anything (no `README`, no `LICENSE`, etc.). This will not create any branch.

Comment: That, or just rename the main branch after creation.

Comment: That would either require a force push or it would mess up the existing history (if different branches are present on GitHub and locally).