# Do I lose my visual studio code file if I uninstall node (and npm)

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

Sorry for the noob question, I need to uninstall node and reinstall it to have a different version and I'm just wondering if that means I'll lose my code or any relevant files on visual studio and whether the new node version will be applied to the existing repository once node has been reinstalled

Comment: There is no relation between the installed Node version and your source files. Your code is not going to be touched when you uninstall and reinstall.

Answer (score 1):

Depends where you've stored your code. If it's not in one of Node's folders (e.g. the Node installation folder or any folder under AppData or similar), it won't be deleted.

Besides, you can (and should!) take a backup of the code if it's precious to you.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't lose any files, as they are probably stored somewhere else other than Node's install directory. If you want to be extra sure, consider [pushing your code to GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17291995/push-existing-project-into-github) or a similar service, so your files are safe there too.